# Microsoft Dynamics Nav ReadMultiple sorting records by specific column

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I use ReadMultiple function to retrieve filtered data from Navision service as below.

```
var customers = postedInvService.ReadMultiple(filtercustomers.ToArray(), CustomerParams.bookmarkKey, -10);
```

This works fine. But my requirement is to first sort from a specific column and get the records. How to give the specific column in order to sort records?

Answer (score 0):

There three different approaches to solve that problem.

1. With the **SOAP Web Service** and `setSize = 0` you get the entire set of results. You can sort the result with [LINQ](http://linqsamples.com/linq-to-objects/ordering/OrderBy-numbers). E. g.

   ```
   var result = from serviceInvoice in
                postedInvService.ReadMultiple(filtercustomers.ToArray(), null, 0)
                orderby serviceInvoice.No 
                select serviceInvoice;
   ```
2. In the Dynamics NAV Development Environment it is also possible to [create a new Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd338838(v=nav.90).aspx) have Fields and Sorting (Property **SourceTableView**) how it is supposed to be.
3. Since Dynamics NAV 2013 Pages can also be fetchef from the **[OData Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh165806(v=nav.90).aspx)** which support server side [sorting](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#OrderBySystemQueryOption) and [filtering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169248(v=nav.90).aspx). E.g. `http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV90/OData/Company('CRONUS%20International%20Ltd.')/postedInvService?$orderby=PostingDate`